# jquery scrollTop() not working in Motoraola Xoom

Tags: jquery, android, xoom

I have a web site to scroll a div (vertically ) using the function scrollTop(). It is not working in Google chrome browser (default) of Motorolla Xoom, Android vertion 3.1 .But it is working in Firefox and all other Android devices. The html and script that I have used is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

setTimeout("heighlit()",1250);

});

function heighlit(){
var fusenTime=Math.random()*100;
var fusenTime=Math.floor(fusenTime);
var pos_list = Math.floor($('#scrolldiv').position().top);
var ele = $('#scrolldiv p:eq('+fusenTime+')')
var pos_fusen_now = Math.floor(ele.position().top) + $('#scrolldiv').scrollTop();
var pos_scroll = pos_fusen_now - pos_list; 
ele.css('background', '#CCCCCC');
try{
$('#scrolldiv').animate({scrollTop:pos_scroll}, 'slow','',function(){
});

}catch(e){
}
setTimeout("heighlit()",1250);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:100px; overflow-y: scroll; width:200px;" id="scrolldiv">
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<    p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
<p>svgasdvsdbvgavg<p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

None of the error messages is showing. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks,
Riyas

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19625

Unfortunately, I don't have a workaround for this yet, either.

See also: [How to scroll an HTML DIV programmatically on Android 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939458/how-to-scroll-an-html-div-programmatically-on-android-3-1)